# How to run densepose on video with Detectron2

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, pose-estimation, detectron

I was wondering if it is possible to run `densepose` annotations on a mp4 with `detectron2`?

In the `projects` folder, you can run `densepose` with `applynet.py` but this only works on images. I tried running this commmand

```
d demo/

python demo.py --config-file ../configs/COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml \
  --video-input video.mp4 \
  [--other-options]
  --opts MODEL.WEIGHTS detectron2://COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/137849600/model_final_f10217.pkl
```

with `densepose` weights and annotations but `Detectron2` gives me this error:

```
Non-existent config key: MODEL.DENSEPOSE_ON
```

I know `DensePose` video exists but it is out of date as it uses `caffe2` separated from `pytorch`.

Is this possible or can you not run on video?

Comment: The line [--other-options] is not to be used literally. This is where you can add other demo.py options if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest approach is to use something like `ffmpeg` to split your video into frames, and then run detectron2 on each frame.